# for each loop and recursion for an arrayList

Tags: java, recursion

I have a problem to understanding this method.
we have a simple implementation of Tree-structure with the composite pattern.
so the tree is for example :

```
                             **1
                            2     erwin
                       true 4 5      6**
```

so root=1 and 2 have the children (true ,4,5) so on....
with this function there are the nodes calculated on a Level:

```
**public int nodeInLevel(int level){
        int out =0;
        if(level==0)    return 1;
        System.out.println("level for forLoop : "+(level)+"  " +out);
        System.out.println("subtrees"+this.subtrees);
        for(Tree b:this.subtrees){
            out += b.nodeInLevel(level-1); 
            System.out.println("level "+(level)+"  " +out);
        }
        return out;

    }**
```

for level 2 ther are 4 and I use the SYSo so I understand how it works and this is the output.

```
level for forLoop : 2  0
level for forLoop : 1  0
level 1  1
level 1  2
level 1  3
level 2  3
level for forLoop : 1  0
level 1  1
level 2  4
4
```

I don't understand why level has not been decremented in the forEach loop because although we recursively call the function knotenInLevel(level-1)
Thanks in advance

Comment: `this.subtrees` is the same across all calls to the code, and you're reusing it in your loop.  There's no indication here that it could be used to advance the distance.  Could you print out what the result of `"teilbaum "  + this.subtrees` actually is?  My hunch is that is where your bug lies.

Comment: no it is not the same . this.subtrees are at  the first call : 2 erwin,  2.call  : true 4 5 and the 3.call 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for(Baum b:this.subtrees){
        out += b.knotenInLevel(level-1); 
        System.out.println("level "+(level)+"  " +out);
    }
```

You don't decrease `level` in this code. You are passing `level-1` to the next recursive method call. This means that in the current execution of the recursive method, `level` remains unchanged.

If you change

```
out += b.knotenInLevel(level-1);
```

to

```
out += b.knotenInLevel(--level);
```

You will pass `level-1` to the next recursive method call, and in addition you will decrement the value of the `level` variable in the current execution of the recursive method.

Comment: aha ok I understand now the difference between level-1 and --level ,but I still don't understand yet why it is then called three times with the same value ??

Comment: @Mem Your loop calls `b.nodeInLevel(level-1)` for each sub-tree. Since you are not changing the value of `level`, all of those calls would have the same value for `level-1`.